# Adding IClientMessageInspector globally to any service reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap-client, service-reference

I Have a .net solution with two seperate projects,
one is a class library and other as a web application.

All of my Service References placed in my class library project. and all bindings and endpoint configurations done programmatically.

In my Web Application I Added a IClientMessageInspector  and BehaviorExtensionElement by reading this link. [How to: Inspect or Modify Messages on the Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733786(v=vs.110).aspx)

I Don't want to add dbcontext access from within my class library, and all my db operations done at web application project.

Now the problem is I want to log every outgoing service call that place in my class library and I Want to configure this globally. (log to db)

for old style web references I was able to add a Soap Extention like the image below, and all calls logged using TraceExtention class.
[image]

I need the same ability using Service References.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same with WCF by adding behavior extensions to web.config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
          <ClientEndpointBehavior />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="ClientEndpointBehavior" type="Custom.WCFMessageInspector, Custom" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

1- Custom.WCFMessageInspector is where your client inspection code reside.

2- Add behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior" to the client endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer is it possible to use default behaviour for clients, I mean 2-Add behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior" to the client endpoint.

Comment: No. It wont apply the extension. The behavior must be set to the one embedding <ClientEndpointBehavior /> which is the exact name of behavior extension element.